# How can i implement the same behaviour as in cluster pattern by apple (NSString and NSCFString)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, class-cluster

I am simply writing the following code for testing purpose:

```
NSString *aStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Foo"];
aStr = [aStr initWithFormat:@"Bar"];//Crashed here
```

I am getting the following error:

```
*** initialization method -initWithFormat:locale:arguments: cannot be sent to an abstract object of class __NSCFString: Create a concrete instance!
```

If i write the following code same thing happen

```
NSString *aStr = [NSString alloc];
aStr = [aStr initWithFormat:@"Foo"];
aStr = [aStr initWithFormat:@"Bar"]; //Crashed here
```

By google I come to know that `initWithFormat` will return the `NSCFString` Object. 
My question is if `NSCFString` is derived class of `NSString` then why I cannot invoke the `initWithFormat` method on `NSCFString`. If it is possible to stop the visibility how can I implement in the code without overriding the method in `NSCFString`(Derived Class).

In simple word If NSCFString is derived class of NSString then why i cannot call the base class (initWithFormat) method on that?

Comment: I don't believe that `initWithFormat` will return `NSCFString`.  Where did you find that out?

Comment: I checked while debugging it shows me isA variable of class as NSCFString

Comment: Have you tried providing some formatting specifiers and using the method as it was intended?

Comment: Can you please provide code snippet what kind of formatting specifiers?

Comment: `NSString *aStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello %@", @"World"];`

Comment: yes the same thing the code is crashing in the second line: [aStr initWithFormat:@"Bar"];

Comment: You should not call `initWithFormat:` on an object that is already initialized. Also where is your format?

Comment: Hi @rckoenes Thanks for the reply But i am not asking for good practice or not. I am asking how can a derived class object cannot call the base class method.

Comment: Because the object return by `initWithFormat:` is not a `NSString`. `NSString` is a [class cluster](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ClassCluster.html). Thus an abstract super class and it returns private, concrete subclasses.

Comment: Yes but cluster class is super class. So derived class instance can call the super class method.

Comment: Yes an abstract super class, thus not al the super class methods have to be implemented in the child classes. Also `NSString` is the super class, the return `NSCFString` is not a child class per say of `NSString` as in not all methods will work and some might throw errors. Which make sense because to code you are writing is not correct and should no be written this way and causes an error to be thrown.

Comment: Insert `NSLog(@"%p:%@", aStr, aStr);` at each line and see what it prints.

Comment: @rckoenes i also asked if the same thing i have to implement in a code how can i do that. Because the way you are telling i tried that the method is only in base class and still my app not crashed in case of my own class cluster

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what's happening is that the `[NSString initWithFormat:]` method is noticing that you have not provided any format specifiers so there is no `NSString` object that needs building, so it's simply returning the constant `NSString` object you pass in (`@"Foo"`):

```
NSString *aStr = [NSString alloc];
aStr = [aStr initWithFormat:@"Foo"];
```

So `aStr` is now of type `NSCFString`.  This is the cause of the crash:

```
aStr = [aStr initWithFormat:@"Bar"]; //Crashed here
```

However you should never be calling an `init` method on an existing object, so to correct the crash use:

```
aStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Bar"];
```

and use format specifiers as you may as well just do:

```
aStr = @"Foo";
aStr = @"Boo";
```

which is the same thing only clearer, uses less code and has better performance.

Comment: Yes but NSCFString is derived class of NSString. As per cluster pattern then why i cannot call the base class method.

Comment: @SauravNagpal You can (and do), however it's designed that if you do it throws the exception you are seeing.

Comment: @ trojanfoe i have to know how can i implement in a code. Should I need to override all the init method of base class?

Comment: @SauravNagpal Well that's a different question, so ask that separately.

Comment: initWithFormat doesn't need any additional parameters if the format string doesn't have a % character in it. That's not the problem. Although it is certainly grating to see such a complicated call instead of just writing @"Foo" or @"Bar".

Comment: @gnasher729 I believe that is the reason for this particular error as `initWithFormat` is performing an optimization by returning the formatting string if there are no format specifiers.

Comment: @trojanfoe sorry for the confusion but i already mention that in my question initially. How can i implement that

Comment: @trojanfoe i posted the question at following link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26607693/how-can-i-implement-the-behaviour-as-in-cluster-pattern-by-apple-nsstring-and-n

Comment: @SauravNagpal That looks like the same question to me.  You will need to elaborate about what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/initWithFormat:) it returns an `NSString` object initialized by using a given format string as a template into which the remaining argument values are substituted.

And also you need to use like that below :-

```
NSString *aStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@,%@",@"Foo",@"Bar"];
NSLog(@"%@",aStr);
```

Comment: I have just done for testing purpose. My question is why it is restricting me to call the base class method again question title "NSCFString Instance cannot invoke initWithFormat"

Answer (score 0):

You are asking "why". Besides the answer "calling init twice on the same object is baaaad" which you ignored, NSString is a class cluster.

[NSString alloc] returns a generic object that isn't really usable as a string but expects an init method to be called. Let's think about something obvious: NSString objects are immutable, but the result of [NSString alloc] cannot be immutable, because otherwise it would be impossible to store a value, right?

That init method will actually return a *different* object that doesn't accept init methods anymore. While [NSString alloc] is a very flexible object that could do anything, after a call to an init method you get an object back that contains a string that can never be modified again.

(Apple may have implemented this differently from what I say or may change their implementation. Nevertheless, they can and will do things that stop you from doing something stupid).

And a warning: Don't even *think* about subclassing NSString. I can guarantee that you won't get anything cobbled together that works.