# How can i implement the behaviour as in cluster pattern by apple (NSString and NSCFString)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I am simply writing the following code for testing purpose:

```
NSString *aStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Foo"];
aStr = [aStr initWithFormat:@"Bar"];//Crashed here
```

I am getting the following error:

```
*** initialization method -initWithFormat:locale:arguments: cannot be sent to an abstract object of class __NSCFString: Create a concrete instance!
```

If i write the following code same thing happen

```
NSString *aStr = [NSString alloc];
aStr = [aStr initWithFormat:@"Foo"];
aStr = [aStr initWithFormat:@"Bar"]; //Crashed here
```

By google I come to know that `initWithFormat` will return the `NSCFString` Object. 
My question is if `NSCFString` is derived class of `NSString` then why I cannot invoke the `initWithFormat` method on `NSCFString`. If it is possible to stop the visibility how can I implement in the code.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with calling `initWithFormat: on a string which is already initialized? You can't modify a `NSString` after it's initialized this way (or any other). Use `NSMutableString` and `setString` method for this purpose.

Comment: @MichałCiuba even NSMutable String is crashing. Please read the question carefully it is regarding Cluster pattern implementation. Not NsSsting Init method called twice or not.

Comment: OK, I got it. Your example is a bit confusing as it instantly makes any Objective-C developer wonder: "Why would anyone ever want to call `init` twice?" :) And it seems no one has understood the question yet, which is "How can I return an object from the `initWith...` method which does not respond to this `initWith...` method" if I understood correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's do some investigation on how `NSString` class cluster works internally:

```
NSString *factory = [NSString alloc];
NSString *theInstance = [factory initWithString:@"I am constant"];
NSLog(@"factory class: %@, instance class: %@", [factory class], [theInstance class]);
```

And the output is:

```
factory class: NSPlaceholderString, instance class: __NSCFConstantString
```

As you can see, the `alloc` method returns an instance of `NSPlaceholderString`. It is a "factory" class which implements all the `init...` methods declared in `NSString`. These methods return concrete (private) subclasses of `NSString`. It returns `__NSCFConstantString` in this example.

If you change the first line to

```
NSString *factory = [NSMutableString alloc];
```

the output will change to:

> NSPlaceholderMutableString, instance class: __NSCFString

So there are different factory classes for the mutable and immutable strings, and those factories return different subclasses.

You can even check the hierarchy of private subclasses in iOS runtime headers: [here](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=__NSCFConstantString) and [here](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/e9f4a9d856d49d910338329371a2ebe321972dc2/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/NSPlaceholderString.h).

---

Now let's see what happens when we call `initWithString:` on an instance of `__NSCFConstantString` we just created.

```
[theInstance initWithString:@"Crash"];
```

As you expected - it crashes. In the stacktrace we can see that `-[NSString initWithCharactersNoCopy:length:freeWhenDone:]` method is called, throwing an exception:

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** initialization method
>   -initWithCharactersNoCopy:length:freeWhenDone: cannot be sent to an abstract object of class __NSCFConstantString: Create a concrete
>   instance!'

So we can guess that this initializer in `NSString` class is actually an abstract method (kind of - there aren't abstract methods in Objective-C, so it throws an exception when called).

This method is implemented in the factory class `NSPlaceholderString`. But it's *not* implemented in all the concrete subclasses, so if you call any of the `init...` methods, it will call the `NSString` implementation which throws the exception.

---

Let's put it all together and build a tiny part of the `NSString` class cluster. It's really simplified and probably totally different than the real implementation, but I just wanted to show the idea.

```
@interface NSPlaceholderString : NSString
@end

@interface __NSCFConstantString : NSString
@end


@implementation NSString

+ (instancetype)alloc {
    return [[NSPlaceholderString alloc] init];
}

- (instancetype)initWithCharactersNoCopy:(unichar *)characters length:(NSUInteger)length freeWhenDone:(BOOL)freeBuffer {
    [NSException raise:NSInvalidArgumentException format:@" initialization method -initWithCharactersNoCopy:length:freeWhenDone: cannot be sent to an abstract object of class %@: Create a concrete instance!'", [self class]];
    return nil;
}

- (instancetype)initWithString:(NSString *)aString {
//this method has to call the "abstract" initializer somewhere. The real implementation is probably more complex, this single line is here for simplicity
    return [self initWithCharactersNoCopy:[aString UTF8String] length:[aString length] freeWhenDone:YES];       
}

@end

@implementation NSPlaceholderString

- (instancetype)initWithCharactersNoCopy:(unichar *)characters length:(NSUInteger)length freeWhenDone:(BOOL)freeBuffer {
    __NSCFConstantString *concreteClassInstance = ...; // create the concrete instance. 
    return concreteClassInstance;
}

@end

@implementation __NSCFConstantString

//implement all the needed methods here. But do NOT implement initWithCharactersNoCopy:length:freeWhenDone:

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSCFString` and `NSCFConstantString` interfaces are private and you shouldn't be using them. While looking at your code, it's hard to discern why you would need to dive into the private subclasses when the public `NSString` superclass does everything you need in an even simpler way:

```
NSString *aStr = @"Foo";
aStr = @"Bar";
```

Or, if you need to use the format:

```
NSString *aStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Foo"];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I am asking how to implement cluster pattern like this so that the NSCFString cannot call the NSString method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot reinitialize an `NSString` since it is a not mutable class, if you want to change a `NSString` after creation, you have to use `NSMutableString`.

However, in your case, you can also use a `NSString`, like this:

```
NSString *aStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Foo"];
aStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Bar"];
```

However, better would be:

```
NSString *aStr = @"Foo";
aStr = @"Bar";
```

if what you are trying to do is to append the string you would do:

```
NSMutableString *aStr = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"Foo"];
[aStr appendString:@"Bar"];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.My question is not about NSSTring init method call I am asking how to implement cluster pattern like this so that the NSCFString cannot call the NSString method.

Comment: The cluster pattern is not done so that `NSCFString` cannot call `NSString` methods, it is done so you can use `NSCFString` as if it was a `NSString`.

Comment: Please see [this explanation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html)

Answer (score 0):

A class cluster is usually implemented with one public class and many private subclasses that derive from the public one so they have the same interface. Check NSNumber. By involving [NSNumber numberWithBool]; that method returns a instance of a subclass of NSNumber specific for bool's while [NSNumber numberWithInt]; returns a instance of a subclass of NSNumber specific for nit's. Both of them chard the same interface, the NSNumber interface.

Answer (score 0):

init methods don't have to return the same object. To implement the same behaviour, just write

```
- (instancetype)initWithSomeArguments
{
    if ((self = [super initWithSomeArguments) != nil)
    {
        self = [[RelatedClass alloc] initWithSomeArguments];
    }

    return self;
}
```