# What is the relationship between NSString and NSPlaceholderString?

Tags: ios, objective-c

The Code like this:

```
char *pStr = "abcs";
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:pStr length:4 encoding:4]);
```

When I disassembled Foundition.framework, I didn't find the function -`[NSString initWithBytes:length:encoding]`. But there was a function like -`[NSPlaceholderString initWithBytes:length:encoding].<br>`

So I made a breakpoint of -`[NSPlaceholderString initWithBytes:length:encoding]`. And then run the above code. The Breakpoint fired.

That's Why? What is the relationship between `NSString` and `NSPlaceholderString`?

can any one give some help? Thank you very much.

Comment: It's private class what Apple uses and we can't say anything about that.

Comment: NSString is implemented as a [Class Cluster](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html)

Comment: What's the purpose of you disassembling `Foundation.framework`? I always get iffy about when people ask questions or say they disassembled something as I think they are trying to steal someone elses code. But as already been said it is a private class that we can't use

Comment: I wrote an answer describing how `NSString` class cluster works, might be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26607693/how-can-i-implement-the-behaviour-as-in-cluster-pattern-by-apple-nsstring-and-n/26610343#26610343